# Errors with WebdriverIO app not connecting to standalone-chrome via docker-compose

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

I'm having an issue trying to dockerize my webdriverIO testing framework and running the tests on the existing selenium/standalone-chrome image with docker-compose.

I have a simple dockerfile to build the app such as this:

```
FROM node:12
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
```

Then I have a docker-compose.yaml to build the stack and run the tests:

```
version: "3"

services:
    app:
        build: .
        command: npm test -- --host selenium
        links:
            - selenium
  
    selenium:
        network_mode: host
        image: selenium/standalone-chrome
        volumes:
            - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
```

My conf.js file sets the host and port like so:

```
exports.config = {
host: 'selenium',
port: 4444,
```

No matter what I try, I continue to get the following error after `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`:

```
[0-9]  Error:  Failed to create session.
app_1       | Unable to connect to "http://127.0.0.1:4444/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
app_1       | If you use services like chromedriver see initialiseServices logs above or in wdio.log file as the service might had problems to start the driver.
```

Any helpful information on why I would see this type of error would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run docker compose but start tests locally pointing to selenium running in docker? Maybe selenium standalone is not starting up properly

Comment: I actually ended up resolving the issue by simply updating the config to use `hostname` instead of host... that seemed to do the trick and link the two containers together to run my tests.

Comment: Can you mark the question as resolved then please?

Comment: Do you have a link to a template repo? I'm trying to do something similar